# the execution result of kotlin coroutine not excepted

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

```
 @Test
fun test():Unit= runBlocking(){
    var count =0
    List(1000){
      GlobalScope.launch() {
          println("${Thread.currentThread().name}       $count")
          count++
      }
    }.joinAll()
    println(count)
  }
```

I except it output less than 1000,but it always output 1000.I tried many times,even change count 10000,it alwaya output 1000 or 10000.When i read the log,it seems to be a thread synchronization problem, but the end result is correct again.Log like this

DefaultDispatcher-worker-7 @coroutine#8       0
DefaultDispatcher-worker-9 @coroutine#10       0
DefaultDispatcher-worker-6 @coroutine#7       0
DefaultDispatcher-worker-4 @coroutine#5       0
DefaultDispatcher-worker-2 @coroutine#3       0
DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#2       0
DefaultDispatcher-worker-8 @coroutine#9       0
DefaultDispatcher-worker-11 @coroutine#12       6
DefaultDispatcher-worker-5 @coroutine#6       0
DefaultDispatcher-worker-3 @coroutine#4       0
DefaultDispatcher-worker-10 @coroutine#11       4
DefaultDispatcher-worker-12 @coroutine#13       10
DefaultDispatcher-worker-8 @coroutine#14       12
DefaultDispatcher-worker-10 @coroutine#15       12
at the end like this
DefaultDispatcher-worker-8 @coroutine#908       899
DefaultDispatcher-worker-9 @coroutine#982       984
DefaultDispatcher-worker-9 @coroutine#998       985
DefaultDispatcher-worker-9 @coroutine#999       986
DefaultDispatcher-worker-9 @coroutine#1000       987
DefaultDispatcher-worker-9 @coroutine#1001       988
DefaultDispatcher-worker-8 @coroutine#997       989
DefaultDispatcher-worker-10 @coroutine#996       990
DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#995       991
DefaultDispatcher-worker-7 @coroutine#994       992
DefaultDispatcher-worker-4 @coroutine#993       993
DefaultDispatcher-worker-5 @coroutine#992       994
DefaultDispatcher-worker-2 @coroutine#991       995
DefaultDispatcher-worker-11 @coroutine#990       996
DefaultDispatcher-worker-6 @coroutine#909       899
DefaultDispatcher-worker-12 @coroutine#907       899
DefaultDispatcher-worker-3 @coroutine#906       899
1000
Can someone explain why this is

Comment: Basically you have here multiple jobs running at once. Each job responsibility is to print log and increment the counter. As those jobs might run in parallel you cannot expect that job2 will print log after job1 incremented you counter. But as each job eventually finishes and increment your counter, final result is 1000. 

This document might be helpful -> https://kotlinlang.org/docs/shared-mutable-state-and-concurrency.html

Comment: While I can't explain your results, I can confirm your understanding of coroutines is correct and we are not guaranteed the count will be 1000. If I removed inner `println()`, it started outputting smaller numbers. I'm not sure why it seems to be always 1000 with this `println()`, but maybe this is because `println()` takes much more time than `count++`, so the risk of concurrent writes is much lower when `println()` is there.

Comment: Also, note that your example is much different than starting say 8 thread/coroutines and incrementing in a loop. Loop is very fast, so `count++` takes relatively big time chunk of a single iteration. In your case we need to schedule a separate coroutine for each iteration. While coroutine switching is pretty fast, it is probably many times slower than simple loop iteration, so the risk of simultaneous `count++` is much smaller in this case.